# MacBook Pro updating to SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, ssd

I have a 15-inch, Late 2011 macbook pro, i mainly use for programming, and occasionally watch a movie or two.

Its getting a bit sluggish, and i reckon its time to update the HD to a SSD one. So my question here is what SSD should i choose, and is there any things i should have a "heads up" with.

I have the stock 500GB HD installed atm. and after all these years i still have 400GB free, so i guess i could manage with a 200-250GB one.

Comment: Check out an OptiBay - you just remove your SuperDrive (DVD) with it. If you need more info, check iFixit :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recommending specific brands and models can be tricky (and this list will probably be out of date in weeks), but at the moment some of the SSD models that get positive comments from Mac users include:

- Samsung 840 Pro series
- Samsung 840 Evo series
- Crucial M500
- Sandisk Ultra Plus

As long as the drive doesn't require any additional software to be installed, you can be almost certain that the drive will work fine with OS X. That said, once you've narrowed down one or two models I'd recommend doing a brief search online to see if there are any drawbacks or known problems, just to be on the safe side.

TRIM won't be supported with a third-party SSD, but you can use [TRIM Enabler](http://www.cindori.org/software/trimenabler/) to work around that.

Personally, I have several Samsung 830 and 840 drives and a Crucial M500 and can recommend them all highly (top of the pile would be the 840 Pro).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Ill look into the Pro series, and see what Ill find out.

Comment: I have a MBP 15" - Mid 2010 with two SSDs (using OWC Datadoubler): Intel 320 and Crucial M500 both working like a charm. I am also using the Samsung 840 Pro in a Lenovo x230 and put it into the MBP just for testing - works great as well. Can only agree to your recommendation.

Comment: The datadoubler looks really cool. Will haveto look into that.

Comment: I've had crucial, and they're great.

Comment: I went with the SS Evo 840 Pro. Fast as hell. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already know the correct answer to your question, I can only agree with you :)

BUT lets examine the "bit sluggish" just in case something else is going on so take look in your Console for repeated errors, or possible Disk I/O

I have the 250 SSD (APPLE SSD SM256E Media) on my MBA and it works like charm, inclusive of plenty of space considering I have like 80 Gig worth of movies and photos on it.

Keeping it clean by deleting stuff from time to time and it will last long time.

Getting a Apple approved SSD is recommended.

Here is how you can [replace the HDD with SSD your self](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Late+2011+Hard+Drive+Replacement/7513).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think my question was a bit unclear, what i really wanted to know was what brand of SSD I should choose. Specially a brand that works 100% with my MacBook. The cost is not relevant, Im searching for a 100% compatible option, with a proven track record.

Comment: PS. By little sluggish, I mean that apps take too much time to open, and as i work everyday on my mac this is getting frustrating. A complete restart also takes forever. I don't thinks theres any errors, just that SSD is faster (a lot faster), i have seen great improvements on other ppl. macs using an SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same macbook and I upgraded to an SSD just last week.
I picked the Samsung 840 Evo series with 200 gb, it really is a very fast drive and especially on booting and wake-up i'm noticing improvements.
In my mac mini i have a crucial m500 240gb and this is just as fast, I would recommend going for one of the main brands at least since they offer good warranty and reliable products.

Answer (score 0):

Intel 530 Series SSD works perfectly in my mid-2009 MacBook Pro.